# Integral with negative intervals

Tags: integration

I try to solve this question like this , if someone can check whether it is right or wrong? $\int_0^1 |e^x - c| \mathrm{d}x.$ When $c\in {[1,e]}$ then i integrate from $0$ to $\ln(c)$ and from $ln(c)$ to $1$.  When $c < 1$ then i try to integrate only $\int_0^1 (e^x + c) \mathrm{d}x.$. 3rd if $c > e$ then i integrate  $\int_0^1 (c -e^x) \mathrm{d}x.$

Comment: Three cases is a reasonable way to do it. It's not clear where you got $(e^x+c)$, however.

Comment: When (C < 1) then for example if i get 0 , then it does not matter but if i get a negative sign it will be multiplied by - sign which is given in problem and i simply add c or i could also write  (e^x - (-c)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrand is not $e^x + c$ in the case when $c < 1$.

There are at least two errors in your reasoning that in the case $c < 1$ you
can rewrite the integral as $\int_0^1 (e^x + c) \mathrm{d}x$.
One error is that there is no indication that you can assume $c$
is an integer; we should consider the possibility that 
$c < 1$ can be satisfied by setting 
$c = \frac12$ (for example), not just by $c=0$ or $c<0$.

The second error is that even when $c < 0$, your formula is the wrong one.
It is true that if $c < 0$ then $\left\lvert c \right\rvert = -c$,
but the original integrand was $\left\lvert e^x - c \right\rvert$, 
not $e^x - \left\lvert c \right\rvert$.

Since $x \geq 0$ everywhere within the interval of integration,
we have $e^x \geq 1$ everywhere within that interval,
so if $c < 1$ then $e^x > c$, therefore $e^x - c > 0$ and
$$\left\lvert e^x - c \right\rvert = e^x - c.$$
The only way this is equal to $e^x+c$ is just when $c=0$; in every
other case when $c < 1$, $e^x - c \neq e^x+c$.

For example, consider $c = -1$.
Then 
$$\left\lvert e^x - c \right\rvert
 = \left\lvert e^x - (-1) \right\rvert = \left\lvert e^x + 1 \right\rvert
  = e^x + 1,$$
but $$e^x + c = e^x + (-1) = e^x - 1.$$

As another example, consider $c = \frac12$. Then
$$\left\lvert e^x - c \right\rvert = \left\lvert e^x - \frac12 \right\rvert = e^x - \frac12,$$
but $$e^x + c = e^x + \frac12.$$

In general, the correct way to deal with $\left\lvert e^x - c \right\rvert$
is to consider the two cases $e^x - c \geq 0$ and $e^x - c < 0$.
If you think about it carefully, you already did this for the case
when $1\leq c \leq e$ by dividing the integral into two parts,
and for the case $c > e$ you found that you always had $e^x - c < 0$
and therefore $\left\lvert e^x - c \right\rvert = c - e^x$.
You just need to apply the same kind of analysis to the case $c < 1$.

Comment: thanks for the correction  :-)

Answer (score 0):

By the monotonicity of the exponential function,

$$\int_0^1 |e^x - e^{\log c}| \mathrm{d}x=-\int_0^{\log c}(e^x - e^{\log c}) \mathrm{d}x+\int_{\log c}^1 (e^x - e^{\log c}) \mathrm{d}x\\
=-(c-1-c\log c)+(e-c-c(1-\log c))=2c\log c-3c+e+1.$$